# Break up MKMap into tiles -- tiles too small

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I am working on an overlay for `MKMapView` using `MKOverlay` and `MKOverlayView`. To start things I just want to divide the world into tiles depending on the current zoom level. So when I am zoomed out I just want to have 1 big tile, next zoom level 4 tiles, then 9 etc. This is working. Now to my problem:

On zoomLevel 3, the tiles start to have gaps between them. This does not happen on zoom level 2 with only 4 Tiles, but in every following zoom level.

```
 _ _ _
|1 2 3|
|4 5 6| <-- Tiles
|7_8_9|
```

The two images show tiles 1,2,4,5 and 5,6,8,9 respectively.

[image] [image]

As you can see the gap increases after each tile. Now to my code:

**drawMapRect:**

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    NSUInteger zoomLevel = [self zoomLevelForZoomScale:zoomScale];
    HeatMap *heatMap = (HeatMap *)self.overlay;
    HeatMapTileManager *tileManager = [heatMap getHeatMapTileManagerForZoomLevel:zoomLevel];
    MKMapRect mapTile = [tileManager getRectForMapPoint:mapRect.origin atZoomLevel:zoomLevel];

    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.5);
    CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();    
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(rgb, (CGFloat[]){ .745, .941, .467, 1 });
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGRect mapTileCGRect = [self rectForMapRect:mapTile];
    CGContextFillRect(context, mapTileCGRect);
}
```

**getRectForMapPoint:**

```
- (MKMapRect) getRectForMapPoint:(MKMapPoint)mapPoint
                       atZoomLevel:(NSInteger)level
{        
    double stepSize = MKMapSizeWorld.width / (double)level;

    double rectIDx = floor(mapPoint.x / stepSize);
    double rectIDy = floor(mapPoint.y / stepSize);

    MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(stepSize * rectIDx,
                                      stepSize * rectIDy,
                                      stepSize,
                                      stepSize);

    NSLog(@"X: %f, Width:  %f", mapRect.origin.x, stepSize);
    NSLog(@"Y: %f, Height: %f", mapRect.origin.y, stepSize);

    return mapRect;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way of tiling is to divide each tile into 4. So the top level has 1 tile. Cut that into 4 and you have you next layer. Cut each of those into 4 and you have your next layer, etc etc. That way a tile on any layer can work out the boundaries of the tiles above or below it very easily and if the data for a layer isn't ready yet it can use a section of the tile above, or join the four tiles below and use that instead.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very good idea, I will change to that. But that wouldn't solve my problem right now would it?

Comment: Well, I have no idea why, but after I changed the tiling, things look as expected. This makes no sense to me, but I'm not gonna complain ;).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out http://tilemill.com for an easier way to tile content for this sort of thing.